# How do I set an event to happen based on an exact time in c#

Tags: c#

Working on hand crafting a binary clock for a class. I was just going to make some labels and have them switch colors based on the time. I was thinking for basic code for a label something like:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour = 1)
    lblHB1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
if (DateTime.Now.Hour = 3)
    lblHB1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
...
else
    lblHB1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

I've tried overcoming the errors myself but I'm getting nowhere.

I'm happy either knowing how to get this code to work, or being told about code that would accomplish the same thing.

Thanks!

Comment: What errors are you experiencing?

Comment: You'll have to elaborate more on how you expect the code to work. Do you have 7 labels which change color (probably blue=ON, gray=OFF) depending on the digit that's displayed?

Comment: Are you using '=' to compare the hours?

Comment: The == fixed my basic problem. Newbies, eh? This would be the label representing the bottom second digit of the hours spot, so I would want it to turn blue on odd numbers 1-9 and be grey otherwise. And I'll set up color changes for the other labels in a way so that they also change to blue for 1 at the appropriate time. Then I can add in automatically sending email reminders and an alarm and such like the project will require. Just getting the basic clock working for now though.

Comment: I got rid of the errors, but it's in the 1:00 range right now and the block turns gray instead of blue. Not sure why.

Comment: @AarronDixon it's gray because of else at the end, if last if is not satisfied else is called, use else if as I suggested

Comment: I followed all suggestions, and it seems the blue isn't activating at all. Even tried it without the else grey at the end and the label just stayed the default color. Let me go try a 24 hour format, I just realized it was 13, and not 1... edited - yeah, that worked. Excuse all the stupidity, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour = 1)
```

to

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 1)
```

You can not assign in an if statement, `=` is for assignment and `==` for comparing, look at [Equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/53k8ybth.aspx).

I suggest you to use **if, else if**, not bunch of if's, like:

```
var hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;

if(hour==1)
{
 ...
}
else if(hour==2)
{
  ...
}
...
else
{
 ...
}
```

with code above you will prevent calling 'else' when last if is not satisfied